# jQuery Page Search Filter - select paragraph text and ahref links

Tags: javascript, search, filter, bootstrap-5

I have implemented a page search filter using Bootstrap 5 but the filter is showing only text content and not any content contained within the **a** tags. Link to JS Fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/mfen723/rozy16pt/17/

I want to make the filter show the content within the **a** tags (as they appear on the page) and to to keep the links clickable.

The filter function I have implemented is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#research *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is change `#research *` to `#research > p`. The first query will return every element under #research, even recursively. The second will only return the `p` elements that are direct children.