# jQuery Search Page Filter - add condition that displays 'no match' when no matching content is found

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following on from s previous post here: [jQuery Page Search Filter - Exclude h4 headings from search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76147197/jquery-page-search-filter-exclude-h4-headings-from-search-results)

I am using Bootstrap 5 with a jQuery search filter which filters the page content and removes any matching h4 headings. The link to the working fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/mfen723/rapcqo0z/6/

The filter function is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#research > *").each(function() {
      $(this).toggle(
        !$(this).is("h4") &&
        $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
      );
    });
  });
});
```

The filter works as I want it to but I want to add a condition that displays 'No match found' underneath the search bar when the search doesn't match any content on the page.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your current fiddle always removes the H4.  Is that your intention?   The toggle condition is slightly confusing - you might be better served with pre-conditioning the h4, assuming you want to keep it:  `$("#research > :not(h4)")` would apply the filter to all lines *except* the H4.

Comment: The issue is that you've only provided a *single* h4+content in your fiddle.   I'm assuming you would want `<h4>1</h4>no results<h4>2</h4>no results` and this layout makes it that much harder rather than grouping the h4+related-p's in a wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are multiple sections comprising of

```
<h4></h4>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h4></h4>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

(of varying length and varying number of h4s)

and the requirement is to get something like:

```
Header 1
no results
Header 2 
result match 1
result match 2
```

Then you can add a `no results` element and use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562633/2181514) to determine if any results were found *per section*.

Typical no results element:

```
<div class='noresults'>no results</div>
```

with css to style and hide by default

Updated code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#research > :not(h4)").each(function() {
      $(this).toggle(
        $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
      );
    });
    $("#research h4").each(function() {
      $(this)
          .nextAll(".noresults")
          .first()                                      
          .toggle(
              $(this).nextUntil("h4").filter("p:visible").length == 0
          );
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.search {
  display: block !important;
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--bg-light);
}

.search input {
  text-indent: 25px;
}

.search input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 2px solid var(grey);
}

.search input.form-control {
  display: block !important;
  width: 700px !important;
}

.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 15px;
}

h4 { border:1px solid red; }

h4 ~ div.noresults { 
  margin-bottom:2em; 
  font-style:italic;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="search">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto" id="research">
      <div class="search my-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mx-auto" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search resources">
      </div>
      <h4 class="sub-heading-alt-resources pb-3" id="#methodologies">Research</h4>
      <p>Ricardo R Bartelme, <a href="https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2164956120973634" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">Anthroposophic Medicine: A Short Monograph and Narrative Review—Foundations, Essential Characteristics, Scientific Basis, Safety, Effectiveness and Misconceptions</a>, published 29 December 2020 in Pub Med, doi 10.1177/2164956120973634</p>
      <p>Mehl A, Brauer D, Didwiszus A, Gelin-Kröz B, Pranga D, Zerm R, Gutenbrunner C (2020), <a href="https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S155083072030224X" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">The Anthroposophic Art Therapy Assessment Paint (AART-ASSESS-P): A peer-report instrument to assess patients’ pictorial expression during Anthroposophic Painting Therapy</a></p>
      <p>Lees J (2001) <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238318617_Reflexive_action_research_Developing_knowledge_through_practice">Reflexive Action Research: Developing Knowledge Through Practice: Counselling and Psychotherapy Research</a> (2001), August 2001, Counselling and Psychotherapy Research 1(2):132-138, <a href="https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14733140112331385178" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">DOI:10.1080/14733140112331385178</a></p>
      <div class='noresults'>no results</div>
      <h4 class="sub-heading-alt-resources pb-3" id="#methodologies2">Research 2</h4>
      <p>Shlonsky A and Gobbs L, <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247903648_Will_the_Real_Evidence-Based_Practice_Please_Stand_Up_Teaching_the_Process_of_Evidence-Based_Practice_to_the_Helping_Professions" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">Will the Real Evidence-Based Practice Please Stand Up? Teaching the Process of Evidence-based Practice to the Helping Professions. Brief Treatment and Criss Intervention.</a> Vol 4. No. 2., January 2004, Brief Treatment and Crisis Intervention 4(2):137-153, <a href="http://mr.crossref.org/iPage?doi=10.1093%2Fbrief-treatment%2Fmhh011" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">DOI:10.1093/brief-treatment/mhh011</a></p>
      <p>Kienle G S, Albonico H U, Baars E, Hamre H J, Zimmermann P, Kiene H (2013). <a href="https://www.hsleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/hsl/lectoraten/antroposofische-gezondheidszorg/artikelgaiham.pdf" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">(pdf, 882 KB )Anthroposophic Medicine: An Integrative Medical System Originating in Europe. ( pdf, 882 KB )</a> Global Advances In Health And Medicine November 2013, Volume 2, Number 6</p>
      <p>Abbing A, Ponstein A, Kienle G, Gruber H, Baars E (2016) The CARE-AAT Guideline: <a href="https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/17454832.2016.1170054?needAccess=true">Development and testing of a consensus-based guideline for case reports in anthroposophic art therapy.</a><a href="https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/17454832.2016.1170054?needAccess=true" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">International Journal of Art Therapy, DOI: 10.1080/17454832.2016.1170054</a></p>
      <div class='noresults'>no results</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've also updated the `$("#research>*")` to `$("#research>:not(h4)")` - it doesn't matter if this includes the `no results` element as that's then re-displayed/re-hidden in the next part.

Comment: Great solution.  Could the function be modified to exclude any h4 headings that don't contain any results (rather than showing 'no result' under the heading)?

Comment: I thought that was the requirement? "*I want to add a condition that displays 'No match found*"

Comment: A small change to the final toggle part: `$("#research h4").each(function() { $(this).toggle($(this).nextUntil("h4").filter("p:visible").length == 0); });`

Comment: I will post a new question regarding my other comments.. Thank you for your help.